# Recording lossless video from USB type capture card

Tags: python-3.x, libvlc

I am using a third party capture card to record HDMI videos for testing purpose. Currently I am only able to record those using VLC media player. There are no command line parameters with the executable to record lossless (or of any type) video. With VLC I am doing

```
Media --> Open Capture device --> Capture Device (TAB)
Select Video device name(Auto detected)
Select Audio device name(Auto detected)
Select Convert from drop down menu
Create new profile  and select RAW and create profile
Select destination for o/p stream and i click start.
```

Now i am able to do above thing  to capture lossless raw video without any encoding.

I want to achieve this via python script. I have checked python-vlc but i have not came across any snippet that is doing recording from USB type capture card.

P.S. This problem has no direct reference to programming only.